# android facebook connectivity on a button click

Tags: android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Integrate Facebook Connect with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498985/how-to-integrate-facebook-connect-with-android)

I am making an android application in which I want to login through facebook id on the click of fbconnect button. 
Can anyone tell me how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is quite generic and I'm not quite sure what your fbconnect button should be - have you tried going through the [Android Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/android/) of the facebook developers page?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/. Download the sample application and play around with it.