# Android how to get feed from facebook fan page?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-login

I need to make an application to a company and would like to display the feed from the fan page of the company that would have a layout similar to the facebook app. The user could comment and give likes (for that he would need to be signed) in posts. But to receive the feed fan page he need not be logged.

I can do this? How do?

Comment: How to integrate facebook with android with the API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498985/how-to-integrate-facebook-connect-with-android

Comment: I can user's login with singleton session, but how to login to fan page of the company directly (I have the user and password)?