# photo feeds from facebook api for android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

How to get feeds(photos only) of a certain Facebook page via Facebook API for android?

is there a straight forward method for that.

Exactly what I need is an activity that shows feeds of photos from a certain page. that why I think this doesn't require login' in. Can I do that? and HOW?

Answer (score 2):

1. For a page, whose **photos** are public you can fetch them without login without any access token, using `/PAGEID/photos`. For eg: http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/photos
2. If you want the public **feeds** pf a page, you can fetch them too, without the login using the `App Access Token`, which you can get using the `\GET` request to :

   ```
   /oauth/access_token?
   client_id={app-id}
   &client_secret={app-secret}
   &grant_type=client_credentials
   ```

   and use this token to query the feeds using `/PAGEID/feed`. For Eg: http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

(I think you need the [Photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) not the [Feeds](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/feed/); to which you are saying *Feeds of Photos*)

If you are new to facebook integration: [How to Integrate Facebook Connect with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498985/how-to-integrate-facebook-connect-with-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try using graph api

`http://graph.facebook.com/pagename?fields=photos.fields(images)`

For more options check the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

Comment: so it is possible to get photo feeds without login in?

Comment: Yes. you can try running in `API Explorer` or `Browser`